# Requesting code review for simple EIP712 validation scheme

Tags: solidity, javascript, signature, eip712

**Hello,**

I am working on a simple EIP712 whitelist member wallet registration/validation scheme. The nutshell goes (sign typed data -> pass to chain -> extract signing address -> compare to signing address stored on chain).

I have been banging my head against this for a while now. **I am not able to get the onchain extracted address to match the signing public address offchain.** My eyes are way too close to this problem and I need help looking for something I may have missed. By my best ability, I appear to be adhering to standard, but obviously I am doing something wrong.

I have been referring to the [EIP712 standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712), the **'Mail' EIP** reference implementation [here (sol)](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/assets/eip-712/Example.sol) + [here (js)](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/assets/eip-712/Example.js), and the **msfeldstein** reference implementation [here (sol)](https://github.com/msfeldstein/EIP712-whitelisting/blob/main/contracts/EIP712Whitelisting.sol) + [here (ts)](https://github.com/msfeldstein/EIP712-whitelisting/blob/main/test/signWhitelist.ts).

**Constraint**

- For reasons, I do not wish to use any framework/OpenZeppelin (and I also have tried, but likewise could  not get to work.)

**Notes**

- The code presented below is basically the EIP reference implementation whittled down, and made as painfully explicit as possible to make the troubleshooting/review process as easy as possible. I likewise cut out all the other testing console.logs.
- My approach has been to generate the `v`, `r`, `s`, and signing public address by running .js and printing to console. I then deploy the .sol to Remix, and manually enter generated values.
- I am likewise posting the question on Ethereum Stack Exchange, etc.
- Alternative typed-data signing methods/strategies are verymuch welcome.

If you have the time and knowhow, I would appreciate your review of my implementation of the EIP712 standard below.

**Clientside:**

```js
// using ethereumjs-util 7.1.3
const ethUtil = require('ethereumjs-util');

// using ethereumjs-abi 0.6.9
const abi = require('ethereumjs-abi');


// The purpose of this script is to be painfully explicit for the sake
// of showing work, to ask for help.


// generate keys

prikey = ethUtil.keccakFromString('cow', 256);
signingAddress = ethUtil.privateToAddress(prikey);
    // 0xCD2a3d9F938E13CD947Ec05AbC7FE734Df8DD826

// data

const typedData = {
    types: {
        EIP712Domain: [
            { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'version', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'chainId', type: 'uint256' },
            { name: 'verifyingContract', type: 'address' },
        ],
        Validation: [
            { name: 'wallet', type: 'address' },
            { name: 'share', type: 'uint256' },
            { name: 'pool', type: 'uint8' }
        ],
    },
    primaryType: 'Validation',
    domain: {
        name: 'Validator',
        version: '1',
        chainId: 1,
        verifyingContract: '0xCcCCccccCCCCcCCCCCCcCcCccCcCCCcCcccccccC',
    },
    message: {
        wallet: '0xeeBA65D9C7E5832918d1F4277DE0a78b78efEC43',
        share: 1000,
        pool: 5,
    },
};

// create domain struct hash

const encodedDomainType = 'EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract)';
const domainTypeHash = ethUtil.keccakFromString(encodedDomainType, 256);

var encTypes = [];
var encValues = [];

        // add typehash
        encTypes.push('bytes32');
        encValues.push(domainTypeHash);

        // add name
        encTypes.push('bytes32');
        encValues.push(ethUtil.keccakFromString(typedData.domain.name, 256));

        // add version
        encTypes.push('bytes32');
        encValues.push(ethUtil.keccakFromString(typedData.domain.version, 256));

        // add chainId
        encTypes.push('uint256');
        encValues.push(typedData.domain.chainId);
    
        // add chainId
        encTypes.push('address');
        encValues.push(typedData.domain.verifyingContract);

    // computer final hash
    domainStructHash = abi.rawEncode(encTypes, encValues);

// create validation struct hash
    
const encodedValidationType = 'Validation(address wallet,uint256 share,uint256 pool)';
const validationTypeHash = ethUtil.keccakFromString(encodedValidationType, 256);

encTypes = [];
encValues = [];

        // add typehash
        encTypes.push('bytes32');
        encValues.push(validationTypeHash);

        // add wallet address
        encTypes.push('address');
        encValues.push(typedData.message.wallet);

        // add share
        encTypes.push('uint256');
        encValues.push(typedData.message.share);

        // add pool
        encTypes.push('uint256');
        encValues.push(typedData.message.pool);

    // computer final hash
    validationStructHash = abi.rawEncode(encTypes, encValues);

// now finally create final signature hash

signatureHash = ethUtil.keccak256(
    Buffer.concat([
        Buffer.from('1901', 'hex'),
            domainStructHash,
            validationStructHash,
        ]),
    );

// and finally, sign

signature = ethUtil.ecsign(signatureHash, prikey);

// convert r, s, and signingAddress into hex strings to pass to remix

console.log(signature.v);

var r = ''
function pad2(s) {return s.length < 2 ? "0" + s : s}; 
    for(i = 0; i < signature.r.length; i++) {
        r += pad2(signature.r[i].toString(16)); }
console.log('0x' + r); // r bytes

var s = ''
function pad2(s) {return s.length < 2 ? "0" + s : s}; 
    for(i = 0; i < signature.s.length; i++) {
        s += pad2(signature.s[i].toString(16)); }
console.log('0x' + s); // s bytes

var str = '';
function pad2(s) {return s.length < 2 ? "0" + s : s};
    for(i = 0; i < signingAddress.length; i++) {
        str += pad2(signingAddress[i].toString(16)); }
console.log('0x' + str); // signingAddress bytes
```

**On chain:**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract validateData {

    address _validationKey = 0xCD2a3d9F938E13CD947Ec05AbC7FE734Df8DD826;

    struct EIP712Domain {
        string  name;
        string  version;
        uint256 chainId;
        address verifyingContract;
    }

    struct Validation {
        address wallet;
        uint256 share;
        uint256 pool;
    }

    bytes32 constant EIP712DOMAIN_TYPEHASH = keccak256(
        "EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract)"
    );

    bytes32 constant VALIDATION_TYPEHASH = keccak256(
        "Validation(address wallet,uint256 share,uint256 pool)"
    );

    bytes32 DOMAIN_SEPARATOR;

    constructor () {
        DOMAIN_SEPARATOR = hash(EIP712Domain({
            name: "Validator",
            version: '1',
            chainId: 1,
            verifyingContract: 0xCcCCccccCCCCcCCCCCCcCcCccCcCCCcCcccccccC
        }));
    }

    function hash(EIP712Domain memory eip712Domain) internal pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encode(
            EIP712DOMAIN_TYPEHASH,
            keccak256(bytes(eip712Domain.name)),
            keccak256(bytes(eip712Domain.version)),
            eip712Domain.chainId,
            eip712Domain.verifyingContract
        ));
    }

    function hash(Validation calldata validation) internal pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encode(
            VALIDATION_TYPEHASH,
            validation.wallet,
            validation.share,
            validation.pool
        ));
    }

    event compare(address sig, address key);

    function verify(Validation calldata validation, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public {
        bytes32 digest = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
            "\x19\x01",
            DOMAIN_SEPARATOR,
            hash(validation)
        ));
        emit compare(ecrecover(digest, v, r, s), _validationKey);
    }
    
}
```

**Thank you for your time and consideration!**